# Which is better: single or multiple database connections?

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, angularjs, connection

I'm making a NodeJS with AngularJS SPApplication with mySQL for backend. The thing is I'm not that good with the backend part and I'm wondering one thing. Is it better to make one big connection to the database and use all the info from it or divide the connection into smaller once and use them on the different views. The example is like this. I have let's say multiple views for superhero database SPAplication. The view that presents a single superhero consists of 4 tabs - biography, history, powers, enemies. Which one is better: to do this for the single superhero view (just an example):

```
var query = '';
    query += 'SELECT s.id, s.nick_name, s.real_name, s.clean_name, s.alignment, s.gender, s.race, s.history, ';
    query += 'p.id AS power_id, p.name AS power_name, p.description AS power_description, ';
    query += 'b.address, zc.city, zc.state ';
    query += 'FROM superhero s ';
    query += 'INNER JOIN superhero_powers sp ON s.id=sp.superhero_id ';
    query += 'INNER JOIN powers p ON p.id=sp.power_id ';
    query += 'INNER JOIN bases b ON s.base_id=b.id ';
    query += 'INNER JOIN zip_codes zc ON b.zip_id=zc.id ';
    query += 'INNER JOIN superhero_enemies se ON s.id=se.good_sh_id ';
    query += 'INNER JOIN superhero sh_enemy ON sh_enemy.id=se.bad_sh_id ';
    query += 'WHERE s.clean_name="'+req.params.sh_clean_name+'"';
```

and have the information for each tab or divide this into multiple connections to  the database and for each tab, when it's clicked to call the connection to get the info for let's say the powers

Comment: This is about single query / multi query not about connections to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Database connections are a limited resource and it is customary that developers would open just the minimum number of connections as possible.

Traditionally applications define a connection pool of some initial predefined size. And every request will be granted a connection from this pool. When the request is done with the connection, it closes it, which actually returns it back to the pool and makes it available for somebody else to use it.

Within a single request it would be rare that you would need more than one connection to the same database.

It does not matter how the view of your application looks, as in this case, it may have multiple tabs (as you call them), but ultimately you will have to communicate with your database server through your http server doing a request. So, this request will be granted a connection from the pool and will use it to get to the database and eventually give you some result. In the mean time, your Web application may have issued yet another asynchronous request, which will be handled pretty much in the same way, another connection from the pool, and all the same story.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you very good. So is it good to make one request for all this stuff and then use them when the user click a link(tab) or should I make separate request for each click depending on which link the user has clicked. (For example separate request to get the powers of a super hero, or the enemies and so on or one request for everything) ?

Comment: @iceless I think you are confusing things. You question was about database connections, now your question is about http requests from the client. Those are totally separe subjects. Your question original question is not clear. You should ask it again but written properly.

Comment: I guess I meant connections sry. I said I'm not familiar with the backend very well - terminology as well. I have
`mysqlPool.getConnection`
Should I make one or divide it into separate ?